# JQuery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookie

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сделать куки для всех страниц сайта?

такая конструкция мне не помогла:

```
$.cookie("blockhide", "openned", { expires: 7}, { path: '/'}, { domain: 'domain.ru'});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многовато объектов передаете)

```
// установка
$.cookie("the_cookie", "the_value", {
  expires: 7,
  path: "/",
  domain: "jquery.com",
  secure: true
});
// удаление
$.cookie("the_cookie", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

а вообще советую обратить внимание на этот плагин
[cookie.js](https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js)

Всё упирается в такие конструкции:

```
cookie.set('key', 'value', {  //установить куку с названием key и значением value
   expires: 7, // на 7 дней
});

cookie.get('key');  //прочитать куку key

cookie.remove('key');   //и удалить ее
```

Кроссбраузерно, использую в своих проектах. Не подводил.